# Set static IP in ESXi VM

Tags: automation, vmware, esxi, static-ip-address

Setup:

I have a setup with several ESXi 5.5 hypervisors (paid licenses) and a vCenter 6.0 linux server instance. I don't have any other infrastructure like vCloud, workstation, etc. I'm using ovftool to deploy a VM from an OVF template. The template that I deploy has no IP configuration when it starts up.

What I'm trying to do:

Automatically configure a static IP address, mask, and gateway through some scripted means. I haven't found a feasible way to do this with ovftool itself.

Requirements:

1. It cannot use DHCP. This infrastructure is not set up in our network and it is not feasible to do so.
2. It must be run in a remote Linux machine, within the command line of the hypervisor, or within the command line of vCenter.
3. It must be a production supported approach (no hacks).

Besides that, I don't really care what language is used to do it. Something ordinary like bash, python, c, java, perl, etc is preferable over something obscure.

If an interface is mentioned (like an API), please note the specific functions that can carry out this operation rather than just saying "oh this interface can/should be able to do that".

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?